# OpenCart - Display child category images - Whilst in the parent category.

Tags: image, opencart

If you take a look at:
http://www.gilliesaudio.co.uk/index.php?route=product/category&path=62

You will see that the products 'Flyers' and 'Posters' have no category image.

And this is as far as I can get in theme/default/template/product/ category.tpl:

```
  <div>
      <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
      <div class="image">
      <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo $category['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" />
      </a>
      </div>

      <?php } ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>">
              <?php echo $category['name']; ?>
          </a>
  </div>
```

No matter how hard I try I can't get the image to show? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance! 
Tom

Answer (score 1):

find this lines in `controller/product/category.php` file :

```
            $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'  => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)
```

and replace them with :

```
            $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_category_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_category_height'));
            $thumb = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], 100, 100); // you can use your own size
            $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                'image' => $image,
                'thumb' => $thumb,
                'name'  => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)
```

and use `$catgory['image']` or `$catgory['thumb']` in the loop

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
```

of the tpl file `view/product/category.php`